# Envers + Spring JPA: revinfo does not allow 'user' column

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-envers, spring-data-envers

I set up Spring JPA + Envers (PostgreSQL) and annotated some entity classes with @Audited. I added my revinfo table because I want to log the account a change came from:

```
@Entity(name = "Audit")
@Table(name = "revinfo")
@RevisionEntity(AuditRevisionListener::class)
class AuditRevisionEntity(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @RevisionNumber
    var rev : Int = 0,

    @RevisionTimestamp
    var timestamp: Long = 0,

    var username: String      <<< CULPRIT
)
```

The above code snipped works! BUT - the moment I rename `username` to `user` everything crashes and burns. I receive a cryptic message

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "user" at character 33
> STATEMENT: insert into revinfo (timestamp, user, rev) values ($1, $2, $3)

My first assumption was that my types don't match, so I verified against my liquibase setup

```
<changeSet id="create-revinfo-table" author="me">
    <createTable tableName="revinfo">
        <column name="rev" type="SERIAL" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="revinfo_pkey"/>
        </column>
        <column name="timestamp" type="bigint"/>
        <column name="username" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

The moment I rename `username` to `user`, it again crashes with the above mentioned error message.

Why can I not use a column called `user` in `revinfo`?
Are there any more of these magic column names?
Where do I find information about this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user` is a [special keyword in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

I would pick a different name but if you feel strong about it [you can quote the name](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-quoted-identifiers) with `@Column`:

```
@Column(name = "`user`")
var username: String
```

Comment: That's what I expected. Thank you for helping out, and thanks for the links. Highly appreciated